# task async datatable on showdialog form problem

Tags: c#, async-await, desktop-application

I want to create the simple async popup windows application, and the windows form is showdialog at end. 
But when I run the program , the program auto exit without error
Can you help me solve , here is my code

```
    private static string pridbUser = "user";
    private static string pridbPwd = "abc123";
    public void run()
    {
        string cnnStr = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=sampledb;User ID=" + pridbUser + ";Password=" + pridbPwd + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [TABLE1]";
        using (SqlConnection sqlcnn = new SqlConnection(cnnStr))
        {
            sqlcnn.Open();
            var tskJob = CreateTableAsync(sql, sqlcnn);                
            using (frmUI ui = new frmUI())
            {
                Task.WhenAll(tskJob);
                ui.BindControl(tskJob.Result.DefaultView);
                ui.ShowDialog();
            }

        }        
    }
    private async Task<DataTable> CreateTableAsync(string sql, SqlConnection dbCnn)
    {

        using (SqlCommand _c = new SqlCommand(sql, dbCnn))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(await _c.ExecuteReaderAsync());
            return dt;
        }

    }
```

Revise, hi , thanks for your comment, then I rewrite the async job, but the result is not my want, the code below :

```
private static string pridbUser = "user";
private static string pridbPwd = "abc123";
public void run()
{
    string cnnStr = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=sampledb;User ID=" + pridbUser + ";Password=" + pridbPwd + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM [TABLE1]";
    using (SqlConnection sqlcnn = new SqlConnection(cnnStr))
    {
        sqlcnn.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Create Table with Asyn mode");
        var tskJob = CreateTableAsync(sql, sqlcnn);                
        using (frmUI ui = new frmUI())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Create Form Complete");
            Task.WhenAll(tskJob);
            ui.BindControl(tskJob.Result.DefaultView);
            ui.ShowDialog();
        }

    }        
}
private async Task<DataTable> CreateTableAsync(string sql, SqlConnection dbCnn)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start to Create Table")
    using (SqlCommand _c = new SqlCommand(sql, dbCnn))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(await _c.ExecuteReaderAsync());
        Console.WriteLine("Delay 5 second")
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // delay 5 seconds
        Console.WriteLine("End Delay")
        return dt;
    }

}
```

The running result is :

```
Create Table with Asyn mode
Start to Create Table
Delay 5 second
End Delay and Return
Create the Form Complete
Bind Control
```

But my expect result should be

```
Create Table with Asyn mode
Start to Create Table
Create the Form Complete
Delay 5 second <-- as it should not wait 5 second and then run form in async process
End Delay and Return
Bind Control
```

Can you have any good advise

Comment: I think you're calling the function without `await`, are you? Can you include the code where you're calling it in?

Comment: `async void run()` is a fire and forget. It will execute on a separate thread to the main thread and not wait.

Comment: @Nkosi I didn't notice it was `void`, that explains it then.

Comment: Hi , for call this class just  
static void Main()
 {
 Application.EnableVisualStyles();
 Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
 
 SampleApps2.SerClass1 cls = new SampleApps2.SerClass1();
 cls.run();
 return;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to await the call to `Task.WhenAll()` (or call `Wait()`, if you can't, as shown in the Examples section of [Task.WhenAll Method doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8).

Also in your `CreateTableAsync` you should await the Task.Delay call.

Here are some suggestions:

```
var tskJob = CreateTableAsync(sql, sqlcnn);   
tskJob.Wait() // Normally, you should use await if possible             
            using (frmUI ui = new frmUI())
            {
                // not needed Task.WhenAll(tskJob);
                ui.BindControl(

(...)

// Change Thread.Sleep(5000); // delay 5 seconds
//to
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

Comment: Thank, I change the code "Thread.Sleep(5000); " into  await Task.Delay(5000);
But I have a question, I try to remove the statement Task.WhenAll(tskJob); is also work.
so from my previous code, do I not need to add Task.WhenAll(tskJob); ?
and what condition need to do ? Thank you

Comment: If you `tskJob.Wait()` then WhenAll is not needed because you already waited for the task.